# check file name in file array list for specific string of char

Tags: java

So I'm writing this program that has to check an array list of files. I need to check the name of the file for a specific string inside the file name.

```
ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));
for(int x = 0; x < file.size(); x++){
  if(file[x] name contains the string "PreProcessReport"){
   do this with file

}
```

The String PreProcess report is just and example. I will need to check for other strings that could be anywhere in the file name that sometimes has ID numbers and such in them, but I figure this is a good start. P.s. this is the first program I am professionally coding, and I am well aware I am a noob. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You mean like [String.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: you have a couple of typos in there. you are using `file` as opposed to `files`.  and use `String.contains()`

Comment: That is my fault for not including what 'file' actually is. It is a File data type var that I stored the folder that is selected by a JFileChooser. I then wanted all the files inside that folder moved to a list. Sorry for the confusion of the variables being close in name. I'm still learning. ALOT! I have only taken a couple of programming classes chasing my 2 year technical degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just translate your sentence to code:

```
if(files.get(x).getName().contains("PreProcessReport")) {
```

Comment: jlordo, you're the man.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few more pointers

- Use `List` as the reference type.
- `for` loop has a typo: count till `files.size()`
- Or, better use the enhanced `for` loop

  ```
  List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));
  for(File file : files){
    if(file.getName().contains("PreProcessReport")){
        // process file
    }
  }
  ```